# Is there any orm-like library for mongodb in scala?

Tags: scala, mongodb, morphia

It seems only the `casbah` we can use in scala, but I hope there is a orm-like library for scala, like `morphia` for java, or something else.

Is there any? I don't want to use `morphia` in scala because I have to convert java collections to scala

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried some of them, but still not find a proper one. Some are hard for scala newbies to get started.

**FINALLY**

Finally, I chose [mongo-scala-driver](https://github.com/osinka/mongo-scala-driver), its awesome. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two solid options:

Salat, which is designed to integrate with Casbah using case classes and scalasig - https://github.com/novus/salat/

Lift (liftweb.net) also has an activerecord ttype library for Mongo which Foursquare has built a DSL, Rogue, for. http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/01/21/rogue-a-type-safe-scala-dsl-for-querying-mongodb/

Comment: Can we use `Rogue` without liftweb?

Comment: No, at the moment Rogue is tied to the Lift Record code.  Casbah has its own DSL built in for querying.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Data is releasing Morphia-like mapping capabilities in the M2 of the MongoDB support. We've talked about doing some native Scala support for this but we haven't had anyone ask for it directly, so its hard to gauge interest. It should be usable as-is from Scala--though there are things I'd like to see us make more Scala-ish.

https://github.com/springsource/spring-data-document

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use morphia in scala because I have to convert java collections to scala

If this is the only reason, I suggest you to use `scala.collection.JavaConversions` It contains implicit conversions from Java to Scalca collections and vice verse.