# Scala Pojos for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala

What is the best way to implement Scala pojos for use with MongoDB?  Looking for a way that is both efficient performance wise and preserves the conciseness of Scala syntax.

I believe this is supported in the latest Mongo driver for Java.  However, I do not see this support in the Scala driver.

Thank You!

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359723/is-there-any-orm-like-library-for-mongodb-in-scala

Answer (score -2):

Following this:

```
class Person {

    private[this] var mName: String = _
    private[this] var mAge: Int = _
    private[this] var mMale: Boolean = _

    // getters

    def name = mName
    def age = mAge
    def male = mMale

    // setters

    def name_= (s: String) = { mName = s }
    def age_= (a: Int) = { mAge = a }
    def male_= (m: Boolean) = { mMale = m }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain how exactly this answers the OP's question.